# How to match there urls not start with a specified name?

Tags: regex

I have a website, it contains many urls, like:

```
/public
/public/images/...
/questions/...
/answers/...
...
```

I want to add some `cache` headers to all the urls except `/public/.*'. But I don't know how to write this regex.

I tried:

```
^(?<!\Q/public/E)/.*
```

But it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess under apache? try:

```
<LocationMatch "^(?!/public/)[^\.]+$"> 
  Header set Cache-Control max-age=7200 
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: @freewind I am not familiar with the syntax you're using - especially \Q, or the "<" character that you're using, so I wouldn't be able to tell why your regex does not work - sorry.

Comment: I mean, in the regex you provide `^(?!/public/)[^\.]+$`, why `\.` is not allowed? From `[^\.]`